# How to call protected function?

Tags: php, inheritance, protected

How to call function `lmn()` without touching class `B` from class `A`

```
 class A extends B{
     public function abc(){
         return "abc";
     }
     ...
 }

 class B{
     public function xyz(){
         return "xyz";
     }
     ...
 }

 class C{
     protected function lmn(){
         return "lmn";
     }
     ...
 }
```

please guide me for this

Comment: You can't. class B (nor class A) doesn't inherit from class C.

Comment: Where do you want to call it?

Answer (score 1):

You can make some kind of proxy class that extends from C and provides a public method for access:

```
class ProcyForC extends C {
  public function getLmn() {
    return $this->lmn();
  }
}

echo (new ProxyForC())->getLmn();
```